# Deleting the app from ItunesConnect and submit as new app due to "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

we submitted one app in "itunes connect" compatable of all devices but now we are planning to restrict to install only for "iphone devices", for that we removed the app from the store and resubmit as new app. My question is what changes we have to make for the new app changing the name from "itune connect",Bundle ID...etc can u help me whether i have to change "app icon" and bundle name in the xcode. What are the things i need to change while submiting as new app ??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: no need to change anything in itunes connect, just declare your app in xcode for particular devices thats all

Comment: "This bundle is invalid. The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the Info.plist may not contain values that would prevent this application from running on devices that were supported by previous versions." message showed due to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1623/_index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to support **more devices then previous version** then you does not need to change any thing in iTunes Store other then you just have to add proper screen shots for supported devices.

But if you want to remove previously supported devices, which are installed in user's devices,then Apple does not accept your build .

> "This bundle is invalid. The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the
>   Info.plist may not contain values that would prevent this application
>   from running on devices that were supported by previous versions."
>
> "This bundle does not support one or more of the devices that were
>   supported in the previous bundle for this app. Bundles must continue
>   to support any devices previously supported."

If you still wants to remove previously supported devices, then you have to upload new build with support you want to provide for devices.

But you can not use same bundle Identifier and same name.

So, your previous user who downloads your previous app have to download this app from App Store.

> Removing your app from the store, and uploading the update with a
>   different bundle ID, will allow you to narrow the range of devices
>   your update supports. However the update will be listed on the store
>   as a separate app. Existing users of your app must purchase the update
>   through the App Store, just like new customers.
>
> Because the update will be treated as a different app, it must have a
>   different name in iTunes Connect than the name of the app already in
>   the store.

For more detail please find here : [Why am I getting device support errors when uploading my app?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1623/_index.html)

Comment: if you change Device category to "Iphone" it won't help, the app is visible to the iPad devices to install. My intention is this "install "option shouldn't be shown to the Ipad devices for that you required UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities as "telephony" just like Instagram app.

Comment: To set telephony true in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities stops app to install in iPod also. So take care of it.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1397/_index.html

Comment: i am facing this issue now developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1623/_index.html, only one solution is submit as new app for that can i use same "app icon" and "bundle name"??

Comment: @VishnuVardhan : You can not upload with same name and same identifier. But i think you can use same App Icon .

Comment: @VishnuVardhan  : Updated answer. Thanks for suggestion. Good Question, which need more attention.

Comment: I removed `sms` from `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` and Apple said  `This bundle is invalid`. Don't know why.